# ARkit(SceneKit)を使った3Dモデルの表示方法

Tags: xcode

ARKitでの3Dオブジェクトの取扱について質問させて下さい。

■ 実現したい事
XcodeのARKitプロジェクトで、defaultの飛行機の3Dオブジェクトのかわりに
Poly (https://poly.google.com/view/1zS7ucaAd4J) でダウンロードしたobj形式の3Dオブジェクトを表示したい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

■ 発生している問題
下記キャプチャの様に、3Dオブジェクトのテクスチャが壊れてしまい正常に表示できません。
※.objファイルは.scnファイルに変換済みです。
こちらは、.mtlファイルが正確に読み込まれていない事が原因でしょうか？
非常に初歩的な質問で恐れ入りますが、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Xcode 9.3上で同じモデルをダウンロード、変換したところ、問題なく3Dオブジェクトとして取り込むことができました。画像を見るとテクスチャが壊れていると言うより、座標のインデックスがずれてしまっているように見えます。何かのソフト(Xcode自体を含む)でモデルデータを編集してしまったと言うことはありませんか?新しいプロジェクトを作ってダウンロードし直すところから始めたらどうなるか試してみてください。

Comment: アドバイスいただきありがとうございます!!
こちら解決致しました。

Xcode上で.objファイルから、.scnファイルに直接変換すると表示が崩れてしまいましたが
Blender ( https://www.blender.org/ ) を利用し、.objファイルを、.daeファイルに変換してからXcodeにインポートし
.scnファイルに変換した所問題なく表示出来ました。

本当にありがとうございました!!

Comment: 先ずは、無事成功したと言うことでおめでとうございます。私はXcode上で直接変換したのですが、バージョン、フォルダー構成、ちょっとした手順の違いなどで失敗するのかもしれません。そちらの方法はほぼ確実そうなので、できれば時間をとって回答としてご投稿ください。

Comment: 回答として投稿致しました。この度はありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちら解決致しました。

Xcode上で.objファイルから、.scnファイルに直接変換すると表示が崩れてしまいましたが Blender ( blender.org ) を利用し、.objファイルを.daeファイルに変換してからXcodeにインポートし .scnファイルに変換した所問題なく表示出来ました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

アドバイスいただき、本当にありがとうございました。